# how load new css forcing page to recache

Tags: amazon-s3, http-headers, cache-control

I have a css file that is stored in AWS S3:

```
 <link href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/my.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I have updated this file by uploading a new file, but the additions are not being loaded in the page.  I can force a recache in the browser by pressing Ctrl + Shift + R, but I don't want every user to have to do this.

I'm new to cache control.  Do I set HTTP headers in S3 in order to force the browser to go and get the new css file with updates?

Comment: Are you planning to use a CDN?

Comment: @Stand__Sure should I use the cloudfront instead of S3?

Comment: Well using CloudFront can won't be able to solve that problem as this is an individual browser caching issue. During development period its recommended to use incognito or caching disabled browser as changes to files such as CSS file are tend to get cached by browsers to speed up the load time and reduce the bandwidth usage. `Ctrl + Shift + R` normally force refresh which clear cache as a part of the process.

Comment: Cloudfront let's you control headers. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html#expiration-individual-objects

Comment: @Stand__Sure so does S3. What control header will make the browser recache the new css file?

Comment: Invalidate the item in Cloudfront